Create/update release draft with latest artifact
I'm searching for a way to create a simple release draft (or update the latest) as the last step in my workflow with the latest uploaded artifact included.
My current workflow file:
name: .NET

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    name: "Build"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          submodules: true
      - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.0.x' # SDK Version to use;
        
      - name: Restore
        run: dotnet restore
        
      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore

      - name: Publish
        run: dotnet publish '${{ runner.workspace }}/ERModsMerger/ERModsMerger/ERModsMerger.csproj' -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile

      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: 'ERModsMerger-SHA${{ github.sha }}'
          path: '${{ runner.workspace }}/ERModsMerger/ERModsMerger/bin/Publish'

It's open source so it can also be found here
How can I achieve this?
I checked possible solutions using release-drafter but I'm not really sure how to implement it in my current code.

Did you try using other actions in your workflow to create the release? Examples: https://github.com/ncipollo/release-action and  https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release

I already checked this and it's not really the behavior I want, I just need the script to create/update an empty draft (no tag or description) with only the latest artifact attached. This way I could manually add tag, title and change notes to the draft without the need to upload myself the artifact.
